# dynamically adding control in async mode

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am using Wpf 4.0. I have a situation where I need to generate dynamic control on a tab control where around 20 tab are generated on run time. These controls are a lots so the control adding process takes time around 1 minute. Is there any way to add control asynchronously.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it would be enough if you only generate the controls for the selected tab. With a flag you can remember whether you have already done the initialization. It is also possible to do this in a thread, but every time a control needs to add is blocking the UI thread.